# Plotting the inverse of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

> The inverse of the function $y=2^x$ is 
>  $\bf (A)$ $y=\log_2x\quad{\bf (B)}\, y=-2^x\quad{\bf (C)}\,y=2^{-x}\quad{\bf (D)}\,y=x^2.$

Need help solving this problem and plotting it on a graph.

Comment: Graph of the inverse function is the reflection of the graph of the original function about the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is $log_2(x)$, *[by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)*. The graph is a reflection of the graph of the original function, as [WolframAlpha will show you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20of%20y%3D2%5Ex):

[image]